# Input/output error while receiving the string from arduino via i2c

Tags: i2c, arduino

Im trying to send string data from arduino to raspberry pi via i2c. 
Raspberry pi can receive the data of particular length(probably32 bytes) of string since *bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0)* read 32bytes only. But the string send from arduino to raspberry pi has length exceed 32bytes. Below code is arduino code.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04
int sensorPin = A3;
int sensorValue;
String str;
String stringOne = "ldr";
//char data[50];
int index = 0;
void setup()
{
Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
Serial.begin(9600);
Wire.onRequest(sendData);
}

void sendData() {
sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
String tagvalue = String("ldr=") + sensorValue;
//Serial.println(tagvalue);
tagvalue = String(tagvalue);
//String tagvalue1;
//tagvalue1 = String(",led=off");
tagvalue = String(tagvalue) + String(",streamkey=98081d09-4359-4b8b-8ba5-f265430155ff");
Serial.println(tagvalue);
//Wire.write('c');
//Serial.println("hi");
Wire.write(tagvalue.c_str());
//delay(1000);
//nWire.write(String("hi").c_str());
//Wire.write(tagvalue1.c_str());


}

void loop()
{
sendData();
delay(5000);
}
```

Raspberry pi code:

```
import smbus
import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address=0x04
data=""
value=""
while True:
  #print 'reading'
  value = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0)
  for i in range(len(value)):
      data+=chr(value[i])
  print data
  time.sleep(2)
  data=""
  value=""
```

This is the string im trying to receiving...

```
"ldr=254,led=on,stream=98081d09-4359-4b8b-8ba5-f265430155ff"
```

Im getting this error in raspberry pi when i try to receiving the above string.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "i2cstr.py", line 8, in <module>
character = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Python smbus module limits itself to SMBus commands which have a 32 byte limit.

You could bit bang or you could use the underlying /dev/i2c-1 device from Python.  You should be able to find examples of both on the www.

My pigpio [Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module implements I2C as well as SMBus commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi()

handle = pi.i2c_open(1, 0x04)

start = time.time()

while (time.time() - start) < 60:

   (length, bytes) = pi.i2c_read_device(handle, 46)

   print(length, bytes)

   time.sleep(2)

pi.i2c_close(handle)

pi.stop()
```

You shouldn't really use address 0x04, it's meant to be a reserved address.

I2C doesn't really lend itself to messages of varying length.  It's probably best to use messages with a fixed size.